# How to make my ubuntu laptop not to use the built-in battery?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, battery-life

I have a Lenovo y50 which I use all day and night. It is plugged in most of the time.

I was wondering if it is possible to make my laptop not to use the battery sometimes and get it out of the circuit and directly use the power from the adapter to keep my battery healthier?

Comment: This won't necessarily work - even if it is possible. Have you looked in your BIOS to see if you can set them min and Max charge level ? If so, setting the vales above 40pct and below 70pct will achieve long battery life.

Comment: remove the battery

Comment: Is this question specific to Ubuntu?

Comment: @davidgo thanks for your advice. But I'm looking for a way to get the battery out of the circuit.

Comment: @Keltari it's not removable And I don't want to open and close my laptop every now and then! of course!

Comment: @Dave I need an answer that would work on Ubuntu since that is the OS I'm currently using.